# Why my custom `tabBar` is not active?

Tags: swift, ios11, tabbar, iphone-x

I have a problem with layout of my custom `tabBar`:
if i adding the layout for iOS-11 (iphone X) the custom bar is not hidden but it dosen't work.
the code of the tabBar controller is this:

```
import UIKit
import SlidingTabBar

class TabBarColorata: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate, SlidingTabBarDataSource, SlidingTabBarDelegate {

var tabBarView: SlidingTabBar!
var fromIndex: Int!
var toIndex: Int!


override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    var tabFrame = self.tabBar.frame
    // - 40 is editable , the default value is 49 px, below lowers the tabbar and above increases the tab bar size
    tabFrame.size.height = 40
    tabFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - 40

    self.tabBar.frame = tabFrame
    self.view.addSubview(tabBarView)
    tabBarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        let guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        tabBarView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor).isActive = false
        tabBarView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor).isActive = false
        tabBarView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.topAnchor).isActive = false
        tabBarView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        tabBarView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true

    }
    else {
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: tabBarView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: tabBarView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: tabBarView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true

        tabBarView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tabBar.isHidden = true
    self.selectedIndex = 0
    self.delegate = self


    //let customTabBar = CustomTabBar(frame: self.tabBar.frame)
    //self.view.addSubview(customTabBar)

    tabBarView = SlidingTabBar(frame: self.tabBar.frame, initialTabBarItemIndex: 0)
    tabBarView.tabBarBackgroundColor = UIColor.white
    tabBarView.tabBarItemTintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.03269767389, green: 0.06364088506, blue: 0.3465765417, alpha: 1)
    tabBarView.selectedTabBarItemTintColor = UIColor.white
    tabBarView.selectedTabBarItemColors = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.03269767389, green: 0.06364088506, blue: 0.3465765417, alpha: 1),#colorLiteral(red: 0.9764705896, green: 0.850980401, blue: 0.5490196347, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.5568627715, green: 0.3529411852, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.4745098054, green: 0.8392156959, blue: 0.9764705896, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.9098039269, green: 0.4784313738, blue: 0.6431372762, alpha: 1)]
    tabBarView.slideAnimationDuration = 0.6
    tabBarView.datasource = self
    tabBarView.delegate = self
    tabBarView.initialTabBarItemIndex = 0
    tabBarView.setup()
    //NSLayoutConstraint(item: tabBarView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leadingMargin, multiplier: 0.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

    //NSLayoutConstraint(item: tabBarView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide, attribute: .leadingMargin, multiplier: 0.1, constant: 0.0).isActive = true



    self.view.addSubview(tabBarView)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tabBarItemsInSlidingTabBar(tabBarView: SlidingTabBar) -> [UITabBarItem] {
    return tabBar.items!
}

// MARK: - SlidingTabBarDelegate

func didSelectViewController(tabBarView: SlidingTabBar, atIndex index: Int, from: Int) {
    self.fromIndex = from
    self.toIndex = index
    self.selectedIndex = index
}

// MARK: - UITabBarControllerDelegate

func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, animationControllerForTransitionFrom fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {

    // use same duration as for tabBarView.slideAnimationDuration
    // you can choose direction in which view controllers should be changed:
    // - .Both(default),
    // - .Reverse,
    // - .Left,
    // - .Right
    return SlidingTabAnimatedTransitioning(transitionDuration: 0.6, direction: .Both,
                                           fromIndex: self.fromIndex, toIndex: self.toIndex)
}


}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you select the tab bar in the Storyboard then go to identity inspector at make sure you are pointing to your custom tab bar class?

Comment: yes i do, in fact the bar is visible but you can't interact

Comment: did you create an Outlet for the tab bar?  I don't see it.

Comment: no because in the guide on github It is not required. i think that the var declaration is the "outlet"